# "if there're opportunities that could be a fit"?

Tags: grammar

"I'm open to new contract opportunities if there're opportunities that could be a fit." --> I think "if there are opportunities that could be a fit" is not correct grammatically? What would be the right way to say?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: hm... since "opportunities" is a plural not singular... i wasn't sure if "a fit"  works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'm open to [many - plural] new contract opportunities if there are [any -one of the] opportunities that could be a fit."

The opportunities can be plentiful but only one will be a fit for the speaker. How many they have to choose from in the end can be plural up until that choice is made.